# How can I add a time stamp to the Blowfish cryptographic algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, timestamp, blowfish

I'm running Java in Eclipse, fyi.

I have plaintext which is encrypted using Blowfish and decrypted on another end.  I want to add a time stamp, such that the encrypted text is different each time for the same plaintext.

How can I add the a time stamp to the blowfish algorithm in Java, such that I can decrypt it on another end?

Thank you.

Here is my encryption code:

```
import BlowfishJ.*;


public class EncryptBlowFishTest {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long CBCIV = 0x0x765904567324590L;

    String pwd = "1234567890";
    int pwdLength = password.length();

    // generate key
            byte[] testkey = new byte[5];


            for (int i = 0; i < testkey.length; i++)
                testkey[i] = (byte) (i + 1);


    BlowfishCBC blowfishcbc = new BlowfishCBC(testkey, 0, testkey.length, CBCIV);

    byte[] tempBuffer = pwd.getBytes();

    // align to the next 8 byte border
            byte[] msgBuffer;
            int n = pwdLength & 7;

            if (n != 0) {
                msgBuffer = new byte[(pwdLength & (~7)) + 8];
                System.arraycopy(tempBuffer, 0, msgBuffer, 0, pwdLength);

                for (int i = pwdLength; i < msgBuffer.length; i++)
                    msgBuffer[i] = 0;
            }
            else {
                msgBuffer = new byte[pwdLength];
                System.arraycopy(tempBuffer, 0, msgBuffer, 0, pwdLength);
            }

            byte[] showCBCIV = new byte[BlowfishCBC.BLOCKSIZE];
            blowfishcbc.getCBCIV(showCBCIV, 0);

            blowfishcbc.encrypt(msgBuffer, 0, msgBuffer, 0, msgBuffer.length);

            String encryptedPwd = BinConverter.bytesToBinHex(msgBuffer);

            System.out.println(encryptedPwd);

    }
}
```

Comment: If you are in CBC with random IV, then it should be different each time. I'm confused.

Comment: The CBC IV is not random, at the moment.  How do I make the CBC IV random?

Comment: @user717236 simple, you create a `SecureRandom` instance (use the parameterless constructor), then you create a `byte[]` with the block size of the cipher. Then you fill the byte array using `SecureRandom.nextBytes()`. Then you need to set it. You can pre-pend the IV to the ciphertext, that's pretty common practice.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use Blowfish over a modern cipher such as AES? Or at least one of the other AES candidates, if you don't like AES for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a random IV, instead. Just generate a random sequence of bytes of the appropriate length and use it as your IV.
Send the IV unencrypted, among with your encrypted message.

**Using a random IV is a standard practice (PKCS#5).**

Comment: Don't I need the IV to be the same on the encryption and decryption ends?

Comment: Send the IV with the ciphertext, it has not to be secret. :)

Answer (score 3):

Make the time stamp the first part of your plain-text, then encrypt everything.

Comment: In other words, put the timestamp at the front of the plaintext and then when it's decrypted on another end, locate and extract the time stamp?

Comment: Yes, or show it as part of the plaintext if it makes sense to the reader. Human readers won't mind it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to zmbq you could simply append `System.currentTimeMillis()` to the text before encrypting. Then when decrypting remove the long. You may want to use a delimiter to make it easier to remove.